# Spring autowire priority with more than two layers

Tags: java, spring

How am I able to override an autowired bean more than once? Consider this 3-layer construct:

**Library 1** defines an interface and a default implementation.

```
public interface Foo {}

@Component
public class FooImpl1 implements Foo {}
```

Throughout all 3 layers the interface will be used for autowiring.

```
@Autowired
private Foo foo;
```

**Library 2** depends on library 1 and provides its own implementation which has to override the first one, i.e. be autowired into existing code of library 1.

```
@Component
public class FooImpl2 implements Foo {}
```

The actual **application** depends on library 2 and also provides another implementation that has to override the former one.

```
@Component
public class FooImpl3 implements Foo {}
```

**How do I configure this?** If there were only two layers, I could use `@Primary` but this doesn't work with more than two layers because `@Primary` can't be overriden again. Is there a more fine-grained way of prioritizing beans that I'm overlooking or can I accomplish a second override using a `@Configuration` or do you simply can not overide a bean more than once and I have to resort to some kind of static helper like `FooProvider.getFoo()` instead of autowiring?

Comment: The @Component will only be found if ComponentScan is enabled. Where dioes this happen? Do you have multiple Configurations or can you simple change the Scan parameters?

Comment: Interesting approach. Of course each layer has a configuration which enables component scan. Thus I would have to disable component scan of the parent layer (or exclude the according package), is that possible?! This would still be inconvenient because each component would need its own package...

Comment: I don't understand. You issue is that you would like to put some order of the beans which implement the same interface when you autowire them?

Comment: Technically, you can exclude by regex or even type, afaik, so you wouldn't have to put everything in it's own subpackage. Another idea, if you have access to all layers, is auto configuration... With `@AutoConfigureBefore` you can let the library 2 auto configure before the library 1. And ever layer uses `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on the `@Bean` definition (instead of ComponentScan) to create the bean only if no other configuration has already created it, so that the order will decide which gets created.

Comment: @george what do you mean with "when"? Throughout all 3 layers it can be autowired in any component by type.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yes, I have access to all layers. This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Strange that I haven't come across one of these annotations before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Be careful, this seems to be limited to Spring Boot, so it might not work on your application: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yeah I know. I do plan to use Spring Boot in my applications. I don't, however, like to have a dependency on Spring Boot in a library. But if it's the best solution, maybe that's worth it. I will also look into type-based component scan though :)

Comment: Technically, you don't need to, it should be enough to put `@Configure` there and only put `@AutoConfigureBefore` in your "last" layer.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is only in Spring Boot, too, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the case, however when you have more than one implementation and want to establish some kind of ordination, existe the annotation @order

```
@order(3)
@Component
public class FooImpl1 implements Foo {}

@order(1)
@Component
public class FooImpl2 implements Foo {}

@order(2)
@Component
public class FooImpl3 implements Foo {}

public class PrintFoo {

List<Foo> fooList;

@autowired
public PrintFoo() {
for(Foo fooImpl: fooList) {
            System.out.println(fooImpl.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
}
```

the output should be:

1. FooImpl2
2. FooImpl3
3. FooImpl1

Comment: But that still leaves all implementations eligible for autowiring. You thus can't use `@Autowired Foo foo;`. Some equivalent that manages _priority_ instead of _order_ would be nice.